# SQL Server: Error when casting varchar(200, null) to decimal(5,2)

Tags: sql-server

I have below SQL Server query:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(myField, ',', '.') as decimal(5,2))
FROM MyTable
WHERE some_condition
```

It is not working. Below error is thrown:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

- myField is of type varchar(200, null)
- myField contains string value 2430

The same error appears if I test it as below:

```
DECLARE @strValue varchar(200) = '2430'
select CAST(REPLACE(@strValue, ',', '.') as decimal(5,2))
```

But below works when specifying varchar length (above error is not shown):

```
DECLARE @strValue varchar = '2430'
select CAST(REPLACE(@strValue, ',', '.') as decimal(5,2))
```

... but in this case result obtained is not correct: 2.00

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The range of precision (total number of digits) for decimal is 38. If you have a huge number in your varchar(200) column... eg one with 150 digits, decimal is not a suitable datatype. You need to think about what you want the results to look like, and what should happen to values that don't fit into that.

Comment: Also, the second one works because when you don't specify how big your varchar is, it defaults to 1 character. So @StrValue is only taking the first digit of 2430 (ie 2) which does fit in decimal(5,2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem, `2430`  is too large. The largest value a `decimal(5,2)` can store is `999.99`. You will need at least 4 digits prior to the decimal place to fit `2430` in a `decimal`, which means your precision must be at least 4 more than than your scale.

```sql
DECLARE @strValue varchar(200) = '2430';
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@strValue, ',', '.') as decimal(6,2));
```

As for why `DECLARE @strValue varchar = '2430'` works, that's because not defining the setting for a data type's length/precision/scale is a [really bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). `DECLARE @strValue varchar = '2430'` is a synonym of `DECLARE @strValue varchar(1) = '2430'` and `'2'` *easily* fits in a `decimal(5,2)`.

Comment: ok, an how to convert any varchar(200) into a correct decimal?

Comment: By ensuring you declare a `decimal` that has the appropriate scale and precision, @Ralph . But a `decimal` can, at most, have 38 digits of precision; if you have a number that is 39+ digits long (as you imply) it won't ever fit in a `decimal`.